# Is it possible to route all traffic from multiple devices through one computer that is attached to a network governed by 802.11x?

Tags: routing, ieee-802.11

I have a laptop (pc1) that is connected to a network governed by 802.11x. I want to route traffic from my other pc (pc2) through pc1 so the network will think that the traffic is from pc1 even though it is from pc2.
Both pcs run windows 7 and I have a tp link router at my disposal.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. Questions by end users of a network not within their control or of a service provider network are considered off topic by this community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. You should contact your IT department as they may have a solution that will meet your needs. Also, providing your own solution may be in violation of security or other policies, which can result in discipline, dismissal and/or legal action.

Comment: What's *802.11x*? (did you mean 802.1x perhaps?)

Answer (score 1):

two solution could be resolve this problem

1. if your PCs have wireless NIC connection may you create add hock connection in pc1 and make pc2 join it   so that pc2 can talk to network through pc1
2. if you have in pc1 NIC with 2 ports or may you install other NIC if not, may you use one of them to establish communication between two PCs and the other to be connected to network  so that pc2 can talk to network through pc1